# Python PIL ImageDraw.text clips text on the left

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, draw, clip, drawtext

I have this very simple example of `PIL.ImageDraw.text`:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
image = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((10, 10), "Test")
image.save("example.png")
```

[image]

The left part of the `T` gets clipped for some reason.

If I add a space character `draw.text((10, 10), " Test")`, I get `Test` as expected, however, obviously it has been shifted to the right from the additional space character.

[image]

Tested on:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) \n[GCC 8.3.0]'
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.__version__
'7.1.2'
```

Same results on:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.8.10 (default, May  5 2021, 03:01:07) \n[GCC 7.5.0]'
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.__version__
'8.2.0'
```

Comment: Images have been scaled 300%

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a font and a size
Most of my errors at the begging with PIL where due to font factors, because it's using a default font type
See this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imagefont-truetype/

Comment: If you'd include a small example snippet how to fix the issue within your answer, that'd be great! For further reading: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)